# How to use copy_if in a vector of vector of char - C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, copy

I have a `vector<vector<char>>` and I am trying to use `copy_if`. This function requires a begin and an end iterator. I know how to use it on a vector. But I don't have any idea of how to use it on a `vector<vector<char>>`.

I have a 5 x 5 `vector<vector<char>>`

```
'a' 'a' 'x' 'x' 'b'
'a' 'x' 'c' 'c' 'd'
'd' 'd' 'd' 'x' 'b'
'a' 'a' 'x' 'x' 'b'
'a' 'a' 'x' 'x' 'b'
```

I am trying to copy all of the characters that are not 'x' into a new `vector<vector<char>>`. So it should look like

```
'a' ' ' ' ' ' ' 'b'
'a' 'a' ' ' ' ' 'd'
'd' 'd' ' ' ' ' 'b'
'a' 'a' 'c' ' ' 'b'
'a' 'a' 'd' 'c' 'b'
```

The other characters kind of fall vertically

This is what I have tried:

```
vector<vector<char>>::iterator row;
vector<char>::iterator col
int i = -1;

for(row = board.begin(); row != board.end(); ++row)
{
    boardCopy.push_back(vector<char>());
    ++i;

    for(col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col)
    {
         copy_if(row->begin(); row->end(), boardCopy[i].begin(), [](char x){return (c != 'x');});
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `std::copy_if` is the right tool as you want to keep the same relative positions.

Comment: Someone may come up with an elegant solution for you, but you might also consider that you may be using the wrong tool for the job. I would just copy the whole vector, strip the `x` characters out, then compact them down. If you don't actually need a copy of the vector you could just strip/compact in place.

Comment: Top tip: what you really want is a 25-element `vector<char>`. Just because it looks like a square on screen doesn't mean you need all the nesting and excess allocation... just write a newline after every 5 elements ;)

Comment: It seems you need to go by column, not by row. Just draw the steps on paper then program them. (`copy_if` is unusable in this case, better to copy "manually").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `copy_if` in this situation is that you still want an insertion into the vector even when `c` is 'x'.
The second problem is that this will not `push_back` the element into the vector. It will actually write to the potentially uninitialized memory after the end of the vector.

You can fix the second problem by using `std::back_inserter` for your output iterator but you still need a different std algorithm. However I think this is making things overly complicated when a simple for loop is much clearer:

```
    vector<vector<char>> table = { /* characters here */ };
    vector<vector<char>> new_table;

    for (vector<char> const& row : table)
    {
        auto& new_row = new_table.emplace_back();
        for (char c : row)
        {
            if (c != 'x') { new_row.push_back(c); }
        }
        new_row.resize(5, ' ');
    }
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pcc84o

Comment: Not a bad attempt, but you're still missing the *The other characters kind of fall vertically* part.

Comment: Indeed. The OP's problem is they went with _"I am trying to copy all of the characters that are not 'x' into a new vector<vector<char>>"_, but forgot about the _"and also copy the ones that were 'x' but give them a new value"_ part. Classic shortcuts in specifications ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, you mean, like tetris ;)

Comment: Whoops somehow I missed that part :p. I will just make this simpler and assume that the array is actually transposed. OP can work out the rest.